# My computer has been making weird noises when starting up and playing games

Tags: hard-drive

My computer has been making weird noises recently. After reading around and investigating a bit, I believe the problem to be with my second Hard Drive. I don't know anything about what numbers are good for read/write...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @John It didn't find any errors. I'm not sure if this command checks both, however as I just edited to my post it is my second hard drive that I believe to be the problem

Comment: @John No problems again

Comment: Well that is great news, thank you very much for helping me out @John :)